# Windows Mobile and a WLAN with SSID containing special characters

Tags: windows-mobile, wireless-networking

In our corporation we have a wireless network which has a name (SSID) which contains some special characters (e.g. ?!@#$%^&*).

Older versions of Windows Mobile (at least 4.x, Windows Mobile 6.1 doesn't have this issue) do not allow typing these into an SSID field in the network configuration dialog. Is there any way to get Windows Mobile devices into the network.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**WiFi Monster**](http://www.wifimonster.net/), it will identify all wireless networks in the vicinity. Click on your company network. Hopefully it will be able to cope with the special characters.

[image]

Comment: The device I'm now trying this with uses a pretty old Windows Mobile version: 2003 Second Edition Version 4.21.1088. Maybe that's why the WiFi Monster didn't install. But I can try with the newer devices with Windows Mobile 6 later...

Comment: Ok, so it does not work with the problematic versions of WinMo and with 6 the issue is not there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to copy-and-paste into the Network configuration dialog, and type the required SSID elsewhere?

Comment: Copy/paste works all right, but when you press enter it says that there are special characters and rejects it.